# If 3 users provide 3 different solutions to the same question, why would one solution not be correct if it solves the issue?

Tags: discussion, answers, wrong-answers

Some developers think differently than other developers, yet come up with different ways to do the same thing, so why would [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32709501/119775) be incorrect, if it does the same thing as the other two, just slightly differently than they proposed?

Comment: Who says they are incorrect?

Comment: people who down voted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709378/how-to-get-maximum-of-two-records-for-each-employee/32709501?noredirect=1#comment53261933_32709501

Comment: I'd say those comments simply indicate you should expand on your answer. It is apparently not clear enough for some what you're trying to say. As for the spam, we do have a load of spam coming in, in the form of  a simple, seemingly okay answer, but with a "suspicious" link somewhere. So I'd forgive that idea.

Comment: If you're only seeing the presentation table there isn't enough information to write a full solution to their question, so you're suggesting that I copy the other solutions into my answer to make a 3 options solution?

Comment: I am never suggesting to copy paste anything from other answers. If you can't make your answer more clear than this, you're going to have to put up with downvotes from those who think you're not addressing the question asked.

Comment: If you get on question block, for down votes on one question, how do you put up with them?

Comment: *"there isn't enough information to write a full solution to their question"* - so vote to close as unclear and/or comment requesting more information, rather than trying to answer.

Comment: You never get a question block for downvotes on a single answer, if for downvotes on an answer at all. What you do is what is outlined in the message informing you of the block. You improve your content.

Comment: Because your answer was misunderstood, you can delete it, and try it once more, with a more carefully elaborated work. People don't always read the text through, just focus on code. So, my suggestion is to add more code to your new answer.

Comment: @GaborSch Do know that deleted posts are still held against your quality record. If the second attempt also fails, now you have two problems....

Comment: yes, but I don't delete my questions, I reword them.  as far as answers go, I change the wording to more effectively answer the questions.

Answer (score 6):

There would be no reason. If the solution does what is asked in the question, and even does the exact same thing as other, correct answers, then logic dictates that it cannot be incorrect.

Now, as for why it was downvoted:

Is it a good answer? Is it clear and properly explained? 
Those who downvoted may be of the opinion that it is not.

And does it really, actually do the exact same thing as the other, correct answers? If there are differences, is it still a good solution? Again, those who downvoted may have reason to believe not.